# Mass file rename

Tags: linux, rename

I would like to mass rename/remove spacing between all my files as below:

[image]

TO

[image]

Basically I want to remove the spacing between SXX EXX on all files in the directory. The other files are named different but the pattern is the same on all of them, they end with SXX EXX

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Copy the text here and apply [code formatting](https://unix.stackexchange.com/editing-help#code).

Answer (score 0):

If you only have those files in the present directory:

`rename 's/01\ E/01E/g' *`

Comment: Thanks for that, that has worked excellent for the files with S01, how can Amend this to match others that start with S02, S03 etc

Comment: Explaination:

rename - renaming multiple files

s - substitue

What are we substituting: here <01 backslash space E> with <01E without space>

since space is a special character, we need to give backslash to make aware that a special character follows it.

g - globally

Using this logic, you can rename, 02\ E with 02E and so on.